# How to handle unsplittable 500 MB+ input files in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a hadoop MapReduce job that is running over all source code files of a complete Debian mirror (≈ 40 GB). Since the Debian mirror data is on a separate machine and not in the hadoop cluster, the first step is to download the data.

My first implementation downloads a file and outputs key=$debian_package, value=$file_contents. The various values (typically 4) per key should then be reduced to a single entry. The next MapReduce job will then operate on debian packages as keys and all their files as values.

However, I noticed that hadoop works very poorly with output values that can sometimes be really big (700 MB is the biggest I’ve seen). In various places in the MapReduce framework, entire files are stored in memory, sometimes twice or even three times. I frequently encounter out of memory errors, even with a java heap size of 6 GB.

Now I wonder how I could split the data so that it better matches hadoop’s 64 MB block size.

I cannot simply split the big files into multiple pieces, because they are compressed (tar/bz2, tar/xz, tar/gz, perhaps others in the future). Until I shell out to dpkg-source on them to extract the package as a whole (necessary!), the files need to keep their full size.

One idea that came to my mind was to store the files on hdfs in the first MapReduce and only pass the paths to them to the second MapReduce. However, then I am circumventing hadoop’s support for data locality, or is there a way to fix that?

Are there any other techniques that I have been missing? What do you recommend?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Hadoop is not very poor when outputting values, but rather you are emitting a huge output string that exceeds your memory size.

Comment: What makes you so sure? I’m outputting BytesWritable objects and reducing them into an ArrayWritable. One instance of the multiple-allocations problem is http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/io/BytesWritable.html#line.121 (1.5x blow-up), another one http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/IFile.java#344 (2x maximum value size allocation). There are more that I haven’t dug into. I’m convinced hadoop is not made for/tested with 500 MB+ output values.

Comment: Implement your own `BytesWritable` that doesn't waste on resizing (why do you resize stuff in the first place?). Usually larger records than the buffer of 64mb will get spilled to disk immediately. No idea why you want to emit 500 mb records though.

Comment: I’m not resizing explicitly, this method is called automatically when deserializing (i.e. feeding to the Reducer). I am aware that big records get spilled immediately. I thought I explained why the 500 MB records: some source tarballs are very big (e.g. 500 MB) and I need to get them from the first MapReduce (download) to the second MapReduce (unpack), before I can split them.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. This is NOT a good case for Hadoop internals. Lots of copying... There are two obvious solutions, assuming you can't just untar it somewhere:

1. break up the tarballs using any of several libraries that will allow you to recursively read compressed and archive files (apache VFS has limited capability for this, but the apache compression library has more capability).
2. nfs mount a bunch of data nodes local space to your master node and then fetch and untar into that directory structure... then use forqlift or similar utility to load the small files into HDFS.

Another option is to write a utility to do this. I have done this for a client. Apache VFS and compression, truezip, then hadoop libraries to write (since I did a general purpose utility I used a LOT of other libraries, but this is the basic flow).